# Loading a properties file from a path that is not in my class path

Tags: java, properties

Hmm simple task but how do i load properties file from path that is not in my class path?

**for example:** i have simple java file that i execute like this :
foo.jar d:/sample/dir/dir/app1.properties
and in the code i do :

```
 public boolean InitConfig(String propePath) {
         prop = new Properties(); 
         try {

            InputStream in =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propePath);
            prop.load(in);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
     }
```

where propePath is :  d:/sample/dir/dir/app1.properties
and InputStream in is always null. 
why does this happen?

Comment: Doesn't `InputStream in = new FileInputStream(propePath);` work?

Comment: You have to load it using the path of the file then.  The getResourceAsStream is for the resources that are available on the classpath.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only resources that can be loaded by `Classloader.getResourceAsStream` are ones in the class (loaders) path. To read properties from an arbitrary path use one of the `load` functions of the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class itself.

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(filePath));
```